# Have to rebuild project every time in Android Studio and Gradle

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio

I have a multi-project build setup in Android Studio 0.5.4 and Gradle 0.9.2 with dependencies on Multiple Android Library Projects and Java projects, and I'm noticing that Gradle thinks my code is UP TO DATE even though I've made changes.

If I change an xml layout file, I can just build and run and changes take effect.  But for code changes, I have to use Build->Rebuild Project.

Comment: mine is even worse. it doesnt even change when i use rebuild :/ i should delete the dependency from my gradle file then clean and re add the dependency and rebuild. some times i need to invalidate caches and restart the android studio :/ google doesnt care about developers while he loves users cuz they make money for him :/

Comment: found a solution ill post it in a minute.

Answer (score 5):

this problem is related to gradle settings. you must disable `configure on demand` in the setting. to disable that, uncheck it in:

```
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Configure On Demand
```

in my own case I wasnt able to see my `.aar` changes even after rebuilding !!! since this option make the build process faster. I only uncheck it whenever there is a change.

UPDATE:
in upper versions of Android Studio you should check "Sync project with gradle before building if needed"

Answer (score 5):

In `Edit Configuration` for **app**, Go to `General` Tab and check that you should have `Gradle-aware Make` added in the general configuration's settings field for `Before-launch`

If it's not added yet than add it by pressing the **+** icon available with `Before-launch`

This solution is applied for **Android Studio 3.3.2 and above**.

For reference see below image.[image]